# ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest cannot export a provider/module

Tags: javascript, backend, nest

This is my app.module code

```
 /* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import {  Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { join } from 'path';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { UserController } from './user/user.controller';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { UsersModule } from 'src/user/user.module';
import { EmailConfirmationController } from './email/emailConfirmation.controller';
import EmailService from './email/email.service';
import { EmailConfirmationService } from './email/emailConfirmation.service';
import { EmailModule } from './email/email.module';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { ClassesModule } from './modules/class.module';
import { ClassController } from './controllers/class.controller';
import { ClassService } from './services/class.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true
    }),
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: configService.get<string>('MONGODB_URI')
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    AuthModule,
    UsersModule,
    EmailModule,
    ClassesModule,
    JwtModule.register({}),
  ],
  controllers: [UserController, EmailConfirmationController, ClassController],
  providers: [AppService, EmailConfirmationService, EmailService, ClassService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This is my class.module code

```
       /* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Class, ClassSchema } from 'src/model/class.schema';
import { ClassService } from 'src/services/class.service';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { User, UserSchema } from 'src/user/model/user.schema';
import { Homework, HomeworkSchema } from 'src/model/homework.schema';
import { ClassController } from 'src/controllers/class.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: Class.name, schema: ClassSchema }]),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: Homework.name, schema: HomeworkSchema },
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [ClassController],
  exports: [ClassService],
})
export class ClassesModule {}
```

This is my email.module code

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import EmailService from './email.service';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { EmailConfirmationController } from './emailConfirmation.controller';
import { EmailConfirmationService } from './emailConfirmation.service';
import { UsersModule } from 'src/user/user.module';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { ClassService } from 'src/services/class.service';
import { ClassesModule } from 'src/modules/class.module';

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule, UsersModule, ClassesModule, JwtModule.register({})],
  controllers: [EmailConfirmationController],
  providers: [EmailService, EmailConfirmationService],
})
export class EmailModule {}
```

Im getting this error of declaration
ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest cannot export a provider/module that is not a part of the currently processed module (ClassesModule). Please verify whether the exported ClassService is available in this particular context.
Possible Solutions:

- Is ClassService part of the relevant providers/imports within ClassesModule?

Please help. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 /* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Class, ClassSchema } from 'src/model/class.schema';
import { ClassService } from 'src/services/class.service';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { User, UserSchema } from 'src/user/model/user.schema';
import { Homework, HomeworkSchema } from 'src/model/homework.schema';
import { ClassController } from 'src/controllers/class.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: Class.name, schema: ClassSchema }]),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: Homework.name, schema: HomeworkSchema },
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [ClassService],
  exports: [ClassService],
})
export class ClassesModule {}
```

You can try this code. It should include the ClassService instead of ClassController. in the provider.

We can not make the provider as controller file.
we make only provider as services file.

Comment: I got this error
[Nest] 21928  - 12/29/2023, 12:09:39 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the EmailConfirmationService 
(JwtService, ConfigService, EmailService, UserService, ?). Please make sure that the argument ClassService at index [4] is available in the AuthModule context.

Comment: `Please make sure that the argument ClassService at index [4] is available in the AuthModule context.` -- Check your `AuthModule`, it should import `ClassesModule`.

Answer (score 0):

The `ClassesModule`  doesn't list the `ClassService` as part of its providers, so it cannot export it. You are also wrongly registering your `ClassController` as a provider here:

```
...
 providers: [ClassController],
...
```

These are the changes you need to make:

```
       /* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Class, ClassSchema } from 'src/model/class.schema';
import { ClassService } from 'src/services/class.service';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { User, UserSchema } from 'src/user/model/user.schema';
import { Homework, HomeworkSchema } from 'src/model/homework.schema';
import { ClassController } from 'src/controllers/class.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: Class.name, schema: ClassSchema }]),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: Homework.name, schema: HomeworkSchema },
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [ClassService], // register ClassService as a provider here
  controllers: [ClassController], // ClassController should be listed as a controller
  exports: [ClassService], // then you can export it here
})
export class ClassesModule {}
```

It seems you are confusing Nest Providers with Controllers, you can learn more about their differences [here](https://samolusola.me/a-deep-dive-into-nest-providers-and-controllers)